# How to format array data in es6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I format array values being inserted to my database?

[image: I want the values inserted similar to the one with yellow underline]

when I tried showing the values on my view,

[image: when I tried showing the values on my view,]

Codes in my submit

```
onSubmit(values) {
    const { mutate, createArea, center } = this.props;
    const data = {
      name: values.name,
      address: values.address,
      days_of_availability: String(values.days_of_availability),
      time_schedule: values.time_schedule.toString(),
      notes: values.notes,
      partnership: values.partnership,
      promotional_ads: values.promotional_ads,
      date_period: values.date_period,
      days: values.days.join(" - "),
      start_time: values.start_time,
      end_time: values.end_time,
      lat: values.lat,
      long: values.long,
      //lat: center.lat.toString(),
      //long: center.lng.toString(),
    }
    createArea(mutate, data)
  }
```

And from my form

```
class AreaForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      daysAvailability: false,
      timeSched: false,
      data: {},
      days: [
        { name: 'Monday' },
        { name: 'Tuesday' },
        { name: 'Wednesday' },
        { name: 'Thursday' },
        { name: 'Friday' },
        { name: 'Saturday' },
        { name: 'Sunday'}
      ],
    }

    this.onToggleDays = this.onToggleDays.bind(this);
    this.onToggleSched = this.onToggleSched.bind(this);
  }
```

How am I be able to insert values similar to the values underlined from the screenshot above. I tried .join(" - ") but the second screenshot shows the output, it still shows [" and "] it is being displayed.

Comment: Can you actually provide the intended result? your question is very scattered.

e.g: `Monday - Tuesday - Wednesday` or `'Monday' - 'Tuesday' - 'Wednesday'`

Comment: Also i'm assuming you are talking about the `days: values.days.join(" - "),` line

Comment: how do you render `days`?

Comment: @TomRowe like this Monday - Tuesday - Wednesday

Comment: @TomRowe this line, outputs ["Monday - Tuesday - Wednesday"], check the second picture.

Comment: `.join` always returns a `string`...  so I guess the problem is in your `jsx`

Comment: which part of jsx @streletss

Comment: omg, the one where you render `days`

Comment: omg this is how i render it <p>{marker.days}</p> @streletss

Comment: it is now being rendered as you shown are you expecting it to be rendered as without square braces right?

Comment: exaclty remove [" and "] @aravind_reddy

Comment: okay, whats the output of `console.log(typeof marker.days, marker.days)`?

Comment: @streletss outputs String ["Wednesday - Thursday - Saturday"].

Comment: so that is why it is rendering the single item so change the way values are inserted into your db if that doesn't work for you you can manipulate that string in js to render as you want

Comment: try to convert array to string

Comment: @aravind_reddy can u please show me how, I am really new to reactjs

Comment: @suisied  I have added my answer please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting response from db as `string` instead of `array` so `join` method is of no use.

If you just need to remove `["` and `"]` from the string you are getting as response then use this:

```
formattedString = marker.days.substr(2) //removes first 2 characters from the string
```

now assign the string by removing the last 2 characters also using slice method

```
days: formattedString.slice(0,-2) //slices last 2 characters from the string
```

**you can do both at a time also:**

```
days: marker.days.slice(2,-2)
```